# How accessing object attributes that are stored in a DataFrame to assess conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, getattr

Please, is there any way to assess conditions on object attributes through `loc` when objects are stored in a pandas DataFrame?

Something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dataclasses import dataclass 

@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class teo(object):
    a : str

te = teo('b')
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[te]})

df.loc[df['c'].getattr('a') == 'b']
```

Above example outputs:

```py
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'getattr'
```

Thanks for your help!
Bests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect; it should be `getattr(teo, 'b')`

To broadcast that across a column, you can use `apply` and an anonymous function:

```
df.loc[df['c'].apply(lambda x: getattr(x,'a')) == 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access each `teo` object individually. One way to do this is through list comprehension.

```
df.iloc[[i for i,v in df['c'].iteritems() if v.a=='b']]
```